# MongoDB password under Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, replication

After installing MongoDB at Ubuntu14.04, a mongodb deamon starts by user "mongodb" at group "mongodb". When modifying the /etc/mongodb.cfg, I need to restart mongod deamon.

But how may i find the password for this user? I tried to modify the password by using "sudo passwd mongodb" and "su mongodb", but the current user is always ubuntu and there is no "authentication failure" exception.

Comment: To restart mongodb just use the command `sudo service mongodb restart` as user `ubuntu`

Comment: @AnanthPai I agree with you. But I hope to know how to "su mongodb" since that is a real account for my OS.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, not all listed in linux are login-able, there are certain users whose main purpose is only for running applications, such as `mongodb`, `mysql` etc. For these users login is disabled in `/etc/passwd` file. Other user created accounts using command `adduser` are loginable. This is explained in a beautiful post in [this](https://serverfault.com/a/576794/373198) post on serverfault.